# Is Sefer Yetsira (The Book of Formation) on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Sefer Yetsira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_Yetzirah) (Book of Formation/Book of Creation) is attributed to Abraham the Patriarch.

> The historical origin of the Sefer Yetzirah was placed by Reitzenstein (Poimandres, p. 291) in the 2nd century BCE. According to Christopher P. Benton, the Hebrew grammatical form places its origin closer to the period of the Mishna, around the 2nd century CE.

I didn't find many questions about it and on Wiki it's saying that modern scholars haven't reached consensus on the question of its origins. Secondly there is no tag for it and searching for 'Yetsira' on the site doesn't show any results.
Are questions based on that book on-topic? If not, why?

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect they are not on topic?

Comment: It's because I didn't find many questions about it and on Wiki it's saying that modern scholars haven't reached consensus on the question of its origins. Secondly there is no tag for it and searching for 'Yetsira' on the site doesn't show any results.

Comment: Perhaps you're our first *Sefer Yetsira* enthusiast?  Please feel free to create the tag -- even better if you also create the wiki for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the help center](/help/on-topic):

> Mi Yodeya is for those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more.
>
> If you have a question about...
>
> - Jewish law or practice (what to do or why)
> - Jewish philosophy
> - a Jewish text (explaining a passage)
> - history of Judaism
> - language used in Judaism
> - general knowledge (science, etc.) as it relates directly to Judaism
>
> ... ([examples](/q/1473)) then you've come to the right place.

*Sefer Y'tzira* is AFAIK considered a text of Judaism. So if you want to have a passage in *Sefer Y'tzira* explained, or have a question about the history of *Sefer Y'tzira* (e.g. its provenance), that would seem IMO to be on topic.

Comment: Is there any tag for it? Or not yet?

Comment: Not that I know of. See Isaac Moses's excellent answer here.

Answer (score 5):

To complement msh210's *de jure* [answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3498/2), here's some *de facto* information that indicates that this community does treat *Sefer Yetzira* as on-topic:

While the transliteration you searched for, "Yetsira," doesn't come up in search results, if you search for questions using the transliteration "Sefer Yetzirah" (the one used for the Wikipedia entry you cited), you'll get (currently) [seven results](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22sefer%20yetzirah%22%20is%3Aq). Two relevant tags that apply to many of these questions are [mysticism-kabbalah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysticism-kabbalah) and [practical-kabbalah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practical-kabbalah).